# How to solve the following differential equation: $y''-(ax^2+b)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-(ax^2+b)y=0$$
Since $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Please report a more complete version of the task or what exactly you want from this equation and its solution. Also consult the Airy-equation to explore the difficulty of this question.

Comment: the solution can not expressed by the known elementary functions

Comment: In what context did this differential equation come up?

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a}\cdot x$ and $du=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a}~dx$. This should give the following:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a}$$
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a}\right)=\frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{dy}{du}\cdot \sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt[4]{a}\right)\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d^2 y}{du^2}\cdot 2\sqrt{a}$$
Substituting into your ODE gives:
$$2\sqrt{a}\cdot \frac{d^2 y}{du^2}-\left(a\cdot \frac{u^2}{2\sqrt{a}}+b\right)y=0$$
Dividing both sides by $2\sqrt{a}$ gives the following:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{du^2}+\left(-\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}-\frac{u^2}{4}\right)y=0 \tag{1}$$

---

Note that equation $(1)$ is in the form of a [Weber Differential Equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Weber_equation), defined as:

> $$\frac{d^2 w}{dz^2}+\left(\nu + \frac{1}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4}\right)w=0 \tag{2.1}$$
>   The above has a [well-known general solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderDifferentialEquation.html) of:
>   $$w(z)=c_1D_{\nu}(z)+c_2 D_{-\nu-1}(iz) \tag{2.2}$$
>   Where $D_{\nu}(\cdot )$ represents the [parabolic cylinder function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function). $\nu$ is a constant.

Applying the above correctly on equation $(1)$ will give the same as @Dr.SonnhardGraubner's general solution, which is easy to do and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

According to Maple, the general solution is

$$ y = c_1 \frac{M(-b/(4\sqrt{a}), 1/4, \sqrt{a} x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} + c_2 \frac{W(-b/(4\sqrt{a}), 1/4, \sqrt{a} x^2)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
where $M$ and $W$ are the Whittaker M and W functions.  It may also be expressed in terms of Kummer M and U functions, or hypergeometric functions.

Comment: How can I get more description to this? 
(If you can suggest topic to read and book).

Comment: [Whittaker functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function)

Comment: I'm asking about the steps to get there (I prefer to study from a book).

Comment: The point is that these are not elementary functions, so elementary methods won't work.  There are all lots of special functions, many of them defined as solutions to second-order linear differential equations with non-constant coefficients, and various transformations will take you from one of these to another.  You might look at books on "Special functions".